# Change CSS with onclick=""

Tags: css

Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong? I want to change the CSS properties when I click on a link.

Found this Suggestion here but isn't working for me.

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('.action').css('display', 'block');">Edit</a>
<div class="action action_2">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">bearbeiten</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">löschen</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button .action {
    position: absolute;
    padding:15px;
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you really, really, really, really shouldn't  be calling it in an `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Even when using VanillaJS he shouldn't do that ;)

Comment: You can just use `.show()` to make it visible. No need to touch CSS in your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, try this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.action').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
</script>
```

And in your HTML.

```
<a href="#" id="link">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you're providing the `onclick` a function *call* instead of a function *reference*.  Your browser expects the latter.

#### Proper way

```
// Javascript
function foo(e) {
    // do stuff, like set the CSS on some elements.  Note 
    // that the 'e' argument is going to be a browser event, 
    // not the element you're changing.
}

// HTML
<div onclick=foo>
// This passes a reference to a function.  Your browser then
// calls foo with an argument of the browser event that was triggered.
```

#### Wrong way

```
// Javascript
function bar(element) {
    // do stuff on the *element* argument.
}

// HTML
<div onclick=bar(someDiv)>
// This is wrong because *bar(someDiv)* isn't a reference to 
// the function, it's a call to run the function with an argument 
// of *someDiv*.  onclick isn't expecting this, so the behavior 
// you'll get will be not what you expect.
```

The specifics of your usage is that `$('.action').css('display', 'block');` is a function call, not a reference.  Your browser is trying to then do `($('.action').css('display', 'block'))(clickEvent)`, and that's not right at all.  So you can wrap your `$('.action').css('display', 'block');` in an anonymous function to make it work the way your browser expects:

```
<div onclick="function(e) {$('.action').css('display', 'block');}">
```

Also note [$().show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/), which may be a handy function for your usage, instead of manually setting CSS properties.  *Also also* consider adding an ID to your HTML element, then use JQuery to attach an onclick handler for that ID (i.e. [$().click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)).

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove the inline JS and try something like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('.action').css('display', 'block');
});
```

The same can be achieved using `$('.action').show();` too.

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pqHeM/1/

Answer (score 0):

Move the action to your JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.action').css({'display':'block'});
    });
});
```